# Why do certain Firefox extensions that rely on external web sites, e.g., Boomerang amd Wayback Machine, not work?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, wayback-machine

Why do certain Firefox extensions that rely on external web sites, such as Boomerang amd Wayback Machine, not work? No error messages are displayed, they just silently fails.

Answer (score 0):

You must disable *first party isolation*, it blocks certain calls to external websites these extensions need.

Open `about:config` and search for `privacy.firstparty.isolate` and set it to `false`.

Comment: That defeats an optional privacy feature of Firefox: https://www.maketecheasier.com/first-party-isolation-firefox/ .

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I know, but that feature isn't enabled by default (AFAIK) and is not available through the regular GUI so it is still kind of experimental. Anyway, it is good to know why something breaks and it took me several days to figure it out. Neither the Wayback Machine nor the Boomerang support could help me. At least you can now make an informed decision if you prioritize privacy or these extensions.